# go-lang on vscode occur error that failed to spawn EPERM

Tags: windows, go, visual-studio-code

I'm using Windows10 and vscode.
I see the following error message when I try to launch:

> "Failed to continue: Error Spawn EPERM"

Here are my code and launch.json.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

//Hello is Http receiver
type Hello struct{}

func (h Hello) ServeHTTP(
    w http.ResponseWriter,
    r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello!")
}

func main2() {
    var h Hello
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:4000", h)
}
```

It is my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": []
        }   
    ]
}
```